# Excel formula several OR

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm having a problem that I looked on several guides in order to understand OR statement.

```
=OR(W6>=100;W6>=90;W6>=80;W6>=75;W6>=69;W6>=40;W6>=20)
```

this is my formula, like that it returns **true**, the thing is I don't want a true writed in the cell I want to write something like "Good", "Bad", etc. I tried to write in the formula cell but it keeps sending an error.

Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `=IF(expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)`

In its original form, you expression is `=OR(W6>=100;W6>=90;W6>=80;W6>=75;W6>=69;W6>=40;W6>=20)`

So it becomes

```
=IF(OR(W6>=100;W6>=90;W6>=80;W6>=75;W6>=69;W6>=40;W6>=20), "Good", "Bad")
```

**BUT** this is just to indicate the general approach. The initial formula itself doesn't make sense, if can be simplified to `=W6>=20`, so you can use

```
=IF(W6>=20, "Good", "Bad")
```